# How to change the summary of a preference placed in a PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, fragment, settings, preferences

I'm developing an app and I'm trying to follow Android guidelines and to use android studio templates.
I'm having various troubles with preference activity and in particular I can't get access to a preference outside the fragment in which it's loaded, i.e. I need to modify the summary of a preference from the activity and not from the fragment, because trying to modify if inside the fragment is impossible given that it's a static class and the method which provides the new value for the summary is non-static (it's a get version method, which uses the getPackageManager non-static method).
Is there a way to acromplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the packageManager from within the fragment. For example:

```
version = getActivity().getPackageManager().
                getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(),  0).versionName;
```

And if you want to do it from the activity, you just need to get a reference to the preference.

First get a reference to the preference within the fragment:

```
Preference myPref;    

public void onCreate(){
    myPref = findPreference("myPref");
}

public Preference getMyPref(){
    return myPref;
}
```

And in the activity you can do:

```
myFragment.getMyPref().setSummary("Preference Summary");
```

You can also call a method on the Activity from the fragment and pass it the preference that you want to update the summary on.

Comment: Man, you made my day! I tried millions of other tricky ways, but without success. To say the truth, I managed to do that in another way, but I really feel this one one is way cleaner and more optimised.

Comment: Please select/vote on my answer if you are satisfied with it. Thanks